# ASUS Transformer - Trying to create/find subscript keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-onenote, tablet

I'm using OneNote 2013 and I need a shortcut for adding subscripts when taking notes in class. Is there any way I can create one?

I tried using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> but that just magnifies the screen.

Comment: Are you using the version that came installed by default, which is the tablet edition in the windows store? The fix is to uninstall that version and download the desktop version from the microsoft site. I had the same issue on my Dell 2-in-1 until I grabbed the desktop version. Not as pretty but the subscript works.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're hitting <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>. This works just fine on mine. If that's not the issue, try finding the program that's hijacking the keyboard shortcut and disabling it.